# what is command of git for retrieve the folder?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am really new to git commands. I created one new projects templates to store my templates created locally. When I created the template project the git shows me sample commands which I followed,

Push an existing folder:

```
cd existing_folder
git init 
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:example/template.git 
git add . 
git commit -m "Initial commit" 
git push -u origin master
```

So, what I did as follows

```
$ git init /templates
$ git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/example/template 

**$ git remote -v origin** 

https://gitlab.com/example/template (fetch) origin 
https://gitlab.com/example/template (push) upstream https://github.com/master/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (fetch) upstream https://github.com/master/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git (push)


$ git push -u origin master 
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': example 
Password for 'https://example@gitlab.com': 
Counting objects: 3, done. 
Delta compression using up to 4 threads. 
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 422 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) To https://gitlab.com/example/template * [new branch] master -> master Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin. 

$ git add . 
$ git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:example/template.git 
fatal: remote origin already exists. 

$ git commit -m "Initial commit" 
[backend e616fdc] Initial commit 488 files changed, 125544 insertions(+) create mode 100644 Desktop/template/css/bootstrap-4.3.1/.babelrc.js
......
....
$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': example
Password for 'https://example@gitlab.com': 
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date

$ git status
On branch backend

$ git add home.html
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory
```

What happens exactly? and even there is no local folder, local folder of my project is also deleted. What should I do? How can I get my local code. Even that code on remote is also not available.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the output of the last git status command? You have nothing to delete your file.

Comment: $ git status
On branch backend
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
$ git add home.html
fatal: Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory

Comment: What is your folders hierarchy? it seems like you're initiating `/templates` folder and you're working from another folder.  Another thing is that you're trying to add second remote as `origin` (`git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:patilarunash/template.git`) and you got rejected because `origin` is already exists. what you tried to do there? try to change it to `git remote add patilarunash git@gitlab.com:patilarunash/template.git` and then try to push to `git push -u patilarunash master`

Comment: I am not moving any other project or directory. I did first command which is $ cd template then I run $ git inti

Comment: @ArunaPatil `template` ≠ `/template`

Comment: @ArunaPatil ‘*Unable to read current working directory: No such file or directory*’ Looks like your working directory is deleted.

Comment: That's what I am saying. I have not deleted the directory. How it is possible?